# Firebase auth logs in but redirect to login at refresh

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make a firebase Auth login with Google. Some features work fine, but everytime I refresh the page when loged in, it loads the login page instead of the page i'm currently in. When this happens im sure I'm still loged in, because i can type the secure URL directly and it loads with auth user info.

Working

- Redirecting to login if not logged in
- Logging in and bein redirected to the main page ("/") after login
- Navigating between pages once loged in

Not working

- I'm being redirected to login screen after refreshing a auth-only
  page, even when im loged in. It should just refresh the page.

Here are my Login, Main, Router and index.js. There are other config files and components, but they work fine.

**Login.vue**

```
<template>
      <el-button plain v-on:click="login" >Iniciar sesión</el-button>
</template>
<script>
import firebase from '../firebaseConfig.js'
export default {
  name: 'Login',
  methods:{
    login: function(){
      let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {
         console.log(result.user.email);
         this.$router.replace("/");
      }).catch(err => console.log(error))
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Main.vue**

```
<template>
<h1>Welcome {{usuario}}
</template>

<script>
import firebase from '../firebaseConfig.js'
export default {
  name: 'Main',
  data () {
    return {
        usuario: "loading..."
    }
  },
  methods:{
    logout: function(){
      firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
        this.$router.replace('login')
      })
    }
  },
  created: function(){  
    this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
      if(this.user) { 
        this.usuario = this.user.email; 
      } 
  }
}
</script>
```

**Router**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Main from '@/components/Main'
import Login from '@/components/Login'

import firebase from '../firebaseConfig.js'

Vue.use(Router)

let router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {   
        path:'*',
        redirect:'/login'
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Main',
      component: Main,
      meta:{
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login    
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to,from,next) =>{
    let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    let requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

    console.log(requiresAuth)
    console.log(currentUser)

    if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
        next('login')
    }
    else if(!requiresAuth && currentUser) {
        next('/')
    }
    else {
        next()
    }
})

export default router
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';
Vue.use(ElementUI);

import firebase from './firebaseConfig.js'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
          router,
          el: '#app',         
          components: { App },
          template: '<App/>'
        })
```

Comment: AFAIK you need to register onAuthStateChanged in order to wait for firebase to load the user from the local-storeage or login via the network. only after that you can issue the router-guard.

Comment: Did you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your main.js file:

```
let app;

firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (!app) {
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
  }

});
```

So you render your app - within the authStateChange Listener

Comment: For starters, you'd get an error because "user" is never used. But also, this just does not work.